# On Premises Service and Firewalls

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, signalr

I have many APIs that run on-premises and a cloud application that talks to them.

We are worried about the amount of effort that its going to take for companies to open their firewall to allow the API exposure to the outside.

I've heard of people using Web Sockets to making an outgoing connection to a server. Has anyone done this and can give me a high level in how your approaching it?   I tried to do some research but don't see a lot of documentation.

I'm familiar with web sockets but a couple questions I would have before implementing them is:

- Is it scalable?  I assume there would be one connection coming out of the server, and then you would have that socket to communicate, or could you have multiple web sockets connect and build some smarts on different sockets to communicate from the calling server?
- What would be the approach to have a Stateless protocol as the initial requests from the consumer and then integrating that with the web sockets?  It seems like I would have to develop a lot of pluming here to manage the requests then integrating it into one or many sockets that are connected as a bridge of sorts.  HTTPRequest ->  Server -> Socket Communication To On-Premises Server -> Server -> HTTPResponse

Any feedback on approaches using web sockets to integrate into on-premise service would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a web socket tunnel for this instead of developing it from scratch.

[Websocket Tunnel](https://github.com/rightscale/wstunnel)